# LinearGradientPaint without coordinates

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, java-2d

I have a bunch of values and appropriate colours:

```
0   Black
20  Dark Grey
50  Light Grey
100 White
```

I want to create a `LinearGradientPaint` to demonstrate that gradient. I can easily calculate the fractions but the `LinearGradientPaint` also requires a starting X, Y and ending X, Y coordinates.

Is there a way I can apply the linear gradient paint to an arbitrarily sized rectangle without knowing the rectangle's size at the point at which the paint is created?

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is not a way to do this.**

You will have to create this object at the time that you paint the rectangle.  If you want to save object creation, my suggestion would be to cache this object when you create it, along with the starting and ending points used to create it.  If the rectangle is still in the same place the next time you paint it, you can use the same paint object.  Otherwise, you will need to create a new one at the new location.

Comment: *"You will have to create this object at the time that you paint the rectangle"* It's pretty easy to create a gradient using 'default' settings then scale & translate it when needed.